# Crazy number puzzle.. Any Mathematicians?

Tags: pattern

Below is a sequence of four-digit numbers and characters that are associated with them.
Can you crack the code and find out what `2963 = ?`

```
8446 = F
5697 = C
2331 = A
1125 = A
1662 = C
4658 = E
8312 = C
6146 = D
4115 = B
8066 = F
```

Comment: I suggest changing the last one into 8466.

Comment: @No.7892142 they'll both be 'F' - see Rand's answer below

Comment: Precisely. Currently, 8066 would be "G" (the 8066 here would be "F", of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2963 equals

> C,

because

> given a number, count the total number of holes in all its digits, add 1, and take the letter at this position in the alphabet.

2331 and 1225 go to A because

> they have no digits with holes,

5697 and 1662 go to C because

> they have exactly 2 holes,

8446 goes to F because

> it has exactly 5 holes,

and so on.

Comment: That was fast ! (or probably due to my first question in this forum). Am unable to accept answer so quickly.

Comment: @S.Krishna Welcome to Puzzling! Unfortunately I think your question counts as a duplicate, since this holes-in-digits thing has been asked before. I'll upvote it and then vote to close, but don't take this the wrong way - it's a good puzzle (as evidenced by its popularity!) and I hope you'll go on to post more nice puzzles here :-)

Comment: Oops, I see it now Q#5734.. And you were the one 'edited' that question long ago !

Comment: @S.Krishna This is at least the 4th duplicate of that question - it's certainly popular!